# Pandas Timedelta in months

Tags: python, pandas

How can I calculate the elapsed months using pandas? I have write the following, but this code is not elegant. Could you tell me a better way?

```python
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([pd.Timestamp('20161011'),
                   pd.Timestamp('20161101') ], columns=['date'])
df['today'] = pd.Timestamp('20161202')

df = df.assign(
    elapsed_months=(12 *
                    (df["today"].map(lambda x: x.year) -
                     df["date"].map(lambda x: x.year)) +
                    (df["today"].map(lambda x: x.month) -
                     df["date"].map(lambda x: x.month))))
# Out[34]: 
#         date      today  elapsed_months
# 0 2016-10-11 2016-12-02               2
# 1 2016-11-01 2016-12-02               1
```

Answer (score 53, accepted):

**Update for pandas 0.24.0**:

Since 0.24.0 has changed the api to return *MonthEnd* object from period subtraction, you could do some manual calculation as follows to get the whole month difference:

```
12 * (df.today.dt.year - df.date.dt.year) + (df.today.dt.month - df.date.dt.month)

# 0    2
# 1    1
# dtype: int64
```

Wrap in a function:

```
def month_diff(a, b):
    return 12 * (a.dt.year - b.dt.year) + (a.dt.month - b.dt.month)

month_diff(df.today, df.date)
# 0    2
# 1    1
# dtype: int64
```

---

Prior to pandas 0.24.0. You can round the date to Month with `to_period()` and then subtract the result:

```
df['elapased_months'] = df.today.dt.to_period('M') - df.date.dt.to_period('M')

df
#         date       today  elapased_months
#0  2016-10-11  2016-12-02                2
#1  2016-11-01  2016-12-02                1
```

Comment: In this way, elapased_months dtype is "object", so I convert "object" into "int64" by using pd.to_numeric(). Thank you for your answer.

Comment: This no longer works directly in Pandas 0.24, where subtracting periods [now gives you a `DateOffset()` object](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew/v0.24.0.html#period-subtraction).

Comment: So, is there is no way of getting the months directly? this is very inpractical

Answer (score 32):

you could also try:

```
df['months'] = (df['today'] - df['date']) / np.timedelta64(1, 'M')
df
#      date      today    months
#0 2016-10-11 2016-12-02  1.708454
#1 2016-11-01 2016-12-02  1.018501
```

Comment: gives `0.919937` for `2018-03-01` and  `2018-02-01`

Comment: I don't recommend using:

"There are two Timedelta units (‘Y’, years and ‘M’, months) which are treated specially, because how much time they represent changes depending on when they are used. While a timedelta day unit is equivalent to 24 hours, there is no way to convert a month unit into days, because different months have different numbers of days."

Answer (score 14):

**Update for pandas 1.3**

If you want integers instead of `MonthEnd` objects:

```
df['elapsed_months'] = df.today.dt.to_period('M').view(dtype='int64') - df.date.dt.to_period('M').view(dtype='int64')
df

# Out[11]: 
#         date      today  elapsed_months
# 0 2016-10-11 2016-12-02               2
# 1 2016-11-01 2016-12-02               1
```

This works with pandas 1.1.1:

```
df['elapsed_months'] = df.today.dt.to_period('M').astype(int) - df.date.dt.to_period('M').astype(int)
df

# Out[11]: 
#         date      today  elapsed_months
# 0 2016-10-11 2016-12-02               2
# 1 2016-11-01 2016-12-02               1
```

Comment: Casting period[M] values to int with ```.astype``` is deprecated now and will raise an error, it is recommended to use ```.view``` instead.

Comment: @PawelKranzberg Thanks a lot for the `.view(dtype='int64')` part. It was crucial for me to see the difference a number or month/quarters/days and not just a string gibberish

Comment: Note that `.view(dtype='int64')` converts NaT to a buffer limit negative.  That can propagate all sorts of weirdness, as pandas will happily do maths with those numbers.

Answer (score 6):

In a simpler way, it can also be calculated using the [to_period](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.to_period.html) function in pandas.

```
pd.to_datetime('today').to_period('M') - pd.to_datetime('2020-01-01').to_period('M')
# [Out]:
# <7 * MonthEnds>
```

In case, you just want the integer value just use `(<above_code>).n`

Comment: got a `'Series' object has no attribute 'n'` error with this when using this in a dataframe. see `map` answer.

Comment: @citynorman
It works for me on _pandas 1.2.4_

`(pd.to_datetime('today').to_period('M') - pd.to_datetime('2020-01-01').to_period('M')).n`

gives an output `20`

Comment: it works for single values but not in a dataframe

Answer (score 2):

Use can use `.n` to get the number of months as an integer:

```
(pd.to_datetime('today').to_period('M') - pd.to_datetime('2020-01-01').to_period('M')).n
```

On a dataframe, you can use it with `.apply`:

```
df["n_months"] = (df["date1"].dt.to_period("M") - df["date2"].dt.to_period("M")).apply(lambda x: x.n)
```

Also takes care of pandas 1.3.2 [int conversion issue](https://github.com/shakedzy/dython/issues/96) and any rounding issues with converting to ints earlier.

Answer (score 1):

The following will accomplish this:

```
df["elapsed_months"] = ((df["today"] - df["date"]).
                        map(lambda x: round(x.days/30)))


# Out[34]: 
#         date      today  elapsed_months
# 0 2016-10-11 2016-12-02               2
# 1 2016-11-01 2016-12-02               1
```

Comment: Sorry for lack of explanation. In this way, the months between 2016-11-30 and 2016-12-02 is 0. I want to get 1 in this case. But it was helpful. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: what about when the number of years cumulate more than 1 month, each year would  cumulate 4 days, for more than 8 years, you mitgh start having false results

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind ignoring the days, you can use numpy functionality:

```
import numpy as np

df['elapsed month'] = (df.date.values.astype('datetime64[M]')-    
                    df.today.values.astype('datetime64[M]')) 
                          / np.timedelta64(1,'M')
```