# Expanding pandas data frame with date range in columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with dates and strings similar to this:

```
Start        End           Note    Item
2016-10-22   2016-11-05    Z       A
2017-02-11   2017-02-25    W       B
```

---

I need to expand/transform it to the below, filling in weeks (W-SAT) in between the **Start** and **End** columns and forward filling the data in **Note** and **Items**:

```
Start        Note    Item
2016-10-22   Z       A
2016-10-29   Z       A
2016-11-05   Z       A
2017-02-11   W       B
2017-02-18   W       B
2017-02-25   W       B
```

---

What's the best way to do this with pandas? Some sort of multi-index apply?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can iterate over each row and create a new dataframe and then concatenate them together

```
pd.concat([pd.DataFrame({'Start': pd.date_range(row.Start, row.End, freq='W-SAT'),
               'Note': row.Note,
               'Item': row.Item}, columns=['Start', 'Note', 'Item']) 
           for i, row in df.iterrows()], ignore_index=True)

       Start Note Item
0 2016-10-22    Z    A
1 2016-10-29    Z    A
2 2016-11-05    Z    A
3 2017-02-11    W    B
4 2017-02-18    W    B
5 2017-02-25    W    B
```

Comment: Thanks! That is very helpful. I was definitely overthinking it.

Comment: Is there another way to accomplish this without iterating row by row?

Comment: i would like to know without iterrows as well.. iterrows is slow for dataset with about 300,000 rows to process.

Comment: @ihightower See my answer below

Comment: @ihightower see my answer please. My answer does not need iteration.

Comment: Is there a way to do this, but without manually specifying the columns to be included in the new dataframe? If you have a dataframe with many columns it starts being cumbersome to manually select all columns to be included...

Answer (score 12):

You don't need iteration at all.

```
df_start_end = df.melt(id_vars=['Note','Item'],value_name='date')

df = df_start_end.groupby('Note').apply(lambda x: x.set_index('date').resample('W').pad()).drop(columns=['Note','variable']).reset_index()
```

Comment: Groupby with apply and a custom function is iteration and often times slower than just using a for loop.

Answer (score 7):

So I recently spent a bit of time trying to figure out an efficient `pandas`-based approach to this issue (which is very trivial with `data.table` in `R`) and wanted to share the approach I came up with here:

```
df.set_index("Note").apply(
    lambda row: pd.date_range(row["Start"], row["End"], freq="W-SAT").values, axis=1
).explode()
```

*Note: using `.values` makes a big difference in performance!*

There are quite a few solutions here already and I wanted to compare the speed for different numbers of rows and periods - see results (in seconds) below:

- *n_rows* is the number of initial rows and *n_periods* is the number of periods per row i.e. the windows size: the combinations below always result in 1 million rows when expanded
- the other columns are named after the posters of the solutions
- note I made a slight tweak to Gen's approach whereby, after `pd.melt()`, I do `df.set_index("date").groupby("Note").resample("W-SAT").ffill()` - I labelled this Gen2 and it seems to perform slightly better and gives the same result
- each *n_rows, n_periods* combination was ran 10 times and results were then averaged

Anyway, [jwdink's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53309617/16330452) looks like a winner when there are many rows and few periods, whereas my solution seems to better on the other end of the spectrum, though only marginally ahead of the others as the number of rows decreases:

| n_rows | n_periods | jwdink | TedPetrou | Gen | Gen2 | robbie |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 250 | 4000 | 6.63 | 0.33 | 0.64 | 0.45 | 0.28 |
| 500 | 2000 | 3.21 | 0.65 | 1.18 | 0.81 | 0.34 |
| 1000 | 1000 | 1.57 | 1.28 | 2.30 | 1.60 | 0.48 |
| 2000 | 500 | 0.83 | 2.57 | 4.68 | 3.24 | 0.71 |
| 5000 | 200 | 0.40 | 6.10 | 13.26 | 9.59 | 1.43 |

If you want to run your own tests on this, my code is available in my [GitHub repo](https://github.com/robbie-manolache/stack-overflow-contrib/blob/main/pd-expand-date-range/run_sims.ipynb) - note I created a `DateExpander` class object that wraps all the functions to make it easier to scale the simulation.

Also, for reference, I used a 2-core STANDARD_DS11_V2 Azure VM - only for about 10 minutes, so this literally me giving my 2 cents on the issue!

Answer (score 5):

If the number of unique values of `df['End'] - df['Start']` is not too large, but the number of rows in your dataset is large, then the following function will be much faster than looping over your dataset:

```
def date_expander(dataframe: pd.DataFrame,
                  start_dt_colname: str,
                  end_dt_colname: str,
                  time_unit: str,
                  new_colname: str,
                  end_inclusive: bool) -> pd.DataFrame:
    td = pd.Timedelta(1, time_unit)

    # add a timediff column:
    dataframe['_dt_diff'] = dataframe[end_dt_colname] - dataframe[start_dt_colname]

    # get the maximum timediff:
    max_diff = int((dataframe['_dt_diff'] / td).max())

    # for each possible timediff, get the intermediate time-differences:
    df_diffs = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame({'_to_add': np.arange(0, dt_diff + end_inclusive) * td}).assign(_dt_diff=dt_diff * td)
                          for dt_diff in range(max_diff + 1)])

    # join to the original dataframe
    data_expanded = dataframe.merge(df_diffs, on='_dt_diff')

    # the new dt column is just start plus the intermediate diffs:
    data_expanded[new_colname] = data_expanded[start_dt_colname] + data_expanded['_to_add']

    # remove start-end cols, as well as temp cols used for calculations:
    to_drop = [start_dt_colname, end_dt_colname, '_to_add', '_dt_diff']
    if new_colname in to_drop:
        to_drop.remove(new_colname)
    data_expanded = data_expanded.drop(columns=to_drop)

    # don't modify dataframe in place:
    del dataframe['_dt_diff']

    return data_expanded
```

Comment: For months, I was able to easily modify this by using `pd.offsets.MonthEnd()` in place of the `pd.Timedelta()`. The other modification was to obtain the timediff column using answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40923820/pandas-timedelta-in-months