# Expand Pandas date range

Tags: python, pandas

I have data that looks like this. Each row represents a value of that ID at some date.

```
ID   Date         Value
A    2012-01-05   50
A    2012-01-08   100
A    2012-01-10   200
B    2012-07-01   10
B    2012-07-03   20
```

I need to expand this so that I have rows for all days. The value of each day should be the value of the day before (i.e., think of the data above as updates of values, and the data below as a timeseries of values).

```
ID   Date         Value
A    2012-01-05   50
A    2012-01-06   50
A    2012-01-07   50
A    2012-01-08   100
A    2012-01-09   100
A    2012-01-10   200
B    2012-07-01   10
B    2012-07-02   10
B    2012-07-03   20
```

Currently, I have a solution that amounts to the following:

- Group by ID
- For each group, figure out the min and max date
- Create a pd.date_range
- Iterate simultaneously through the rows and through the date range, filling the values in the date range and incrementing the index-pointer to the rows if necessary
- Append all these date ranges to a final dataframe

It works, but seems like a pretty bad bruteforce solution. I wonder if there's a better approach supported by Pandas?

Comment: Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42151886/expanding-pandas-data-frame-with-date-range-in-columns but not quite the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using [`resample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) on `Date` indexed dataframe with `ID` groups and `ffill` on `value`

```
In [1725]: df.set_index('Date').groupby('ID').resample('1D')['Value'].ffill().reset_index()
Out[1725]:
  ID       Date  Value
0  A 2012-01-05     50
1  A 2012-01-06     50
2  A 2012-01-07     50
3  A 2012-01-08    100
4  A 2012-01-09    100
5  A 2012-01-10    200
6  B 2012-07-01     10
7  B 2012-07-02     10
8  B 2012-07-03     20
```

Comment: Oh wow, a one liner! Does 1D refer to 1 day? What if I had the same kind of data, but wanted start-of-month dates?

Comment: Yes, check alias at http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#offset-aliases

Answer (score 1):

Or you can try this one (***Notice*** : this can be used for expend numeric column too ).

```
df.Date=pd.to_datetime(df.Date)
df=df.set_index(df.Date)
df.set_index(df.Date).groupby('ID')\
   .apply(lambda x : x.reindex(pd.date_range(min(x.index), max(x.index),freq='D')))\
     .ffill().reset_index(drop=True)

Out[519]: 
  ID       Date  Value
0  A 2012-01-05   50.0
1  A 2012-01-05   50.0
2  A 2012-01-05   50.0
3  A 2012-01-08  100.0
4  A 2012-01-08  100.0
5  A 2012-01-10  200.0
6  B 2012-07-01   10.0
7  B 2012-07-01   10.0
8  B 2012-07-03   20.0
```

Comment: Hmm this does not match the output in the OP?