# Pandas Dataframe rows average based on value interval

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame that contains a list of thousands of, let's say, cars. Each car has a Start year column and an End year column, which represents the interval of years the car has circulated. Each car also has an average fuel consumption column for the whole period, like so:

```
df_cars
+-----+------------+----------+--------------------------+
| Car | Start year | End year | Average fuel consumption |
+-----+------------+----------+--------------------------+
| 1   | 2002       | 2025     | 10.0                     |
+-----+------------+----------+--------------------------+
| 2   | 1995       | 2008     | 12.5                     |
+-----+------------+----------+--------------------------+
| 3   | 2005       | 2017     | 8.5                      |
+-----+------------+----------+--------------------------+
```

For a period between 2000 and 2015, I would like to obtain an average fuel consumption of the fleet of cars operating each year "Y". Hence, if a car has a Start year < Y and an End year > Y, it should be included in the average of the fleet for that given year. Obviously, most cars will appear in the fleet average of several years.

As of now, I am doing a loop, but it is rather slow.

```
for y in range(2000, 2015):
    df_cars[(df_cars["Start year"]<=int(y))&(df_cars["End year"]>=int(y))]["Average fuel consumption"].mean(axis=0)
```

Is there a faster way of doing this?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way using `collections.Counter`.

It is *not* vectorised, but still appears to offer a 13x performance improvement.

There is a pandonic but still loopy alternative [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42152199/9209546), but I cannot find a vectorised implementation.

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import Counter

df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2002, 2025, 10.0],
                   [2, 1995, 2008, 12.5],
                   [3, 2005, 2017, 8.5]],
                  columns=['Car', 'StartYear', 'EndYear', 'AvgFuelConsumption'])

def jp(df):

    # first get range of years
    year_range = range(df['StartYear'].min(), df['EndYear'].max()+1)

    res = pd.DataFrame(index=year_range, columns=['AvgFuelConsumption'])

    # use collections.Counter for sums and counts
    c_sum = Counter()
    c_count = Counter()
    for idx, car, start, end, fuel in df.itertuples():
        for i in range(start, end+1):
            c_sum[i] += fuel
            c_count[i] += 1

    # calculate averages by year
    c_res = {y: c_sum[y] / c_count[y] for y in c_sum}

    # create dataframe from dictionary
    res = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(c_res, orient='index')

    return res

def original(df):

    res = pd.DataFrame(index=range(2000, 2026), columns=['AvgFuelConsumption'])

    for y in range(2000, 2026):
        res.loc[y, 'AvgFuelConsumption'] = df[(df["StartYear"]<=int(y))&(df["EndYear"]>=int(y))]["AvgFuelConsumption"].mean(axis=0)

    return res

%timeit jp(df)        # 4.17ms
%timeit original(df)  # 54.8ms
```

Comment: Thank you. Much faster indeed!