# Create weekly time series by interpolating dates between two existing columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How to convert the 'source dataframe' to 'target dataframe' using pandas?

Source Dataframe's datefrom and dateto are date range, I want convert to the date range as per week like as the result 'targe dataframe'.

## Source Dataframe

```
DateFrom    DateTo      Catalog  Score
2017-05-01  2017-05-21  ABC      20
2017-05-22  2017-06-04  WXY      30
```

## Target Dateframe

```
DateFrom    DateTo      Catalog  Score
2017-05-01  2017-05-07  ABC      20
2017-05-08  2017-05-14  ABC      20
2017-05-15  2017-05-21  ABC      20
2017-05-22  2017-05-28  WXY      30
2017-05-29  2017-06-04  WXY      30
```

Comment: I updated your title to better capture what I think is the focus of your question.  Please feel free to change back (or better, to update to be more specific in your own words) if I didn't get it quite right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extending the answer to a similar question here [Expanding pandas data frame with date range in columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42151886/expanding-pandas-data-frame-with-date-range-in-columns]), You can iterate through each row and expand your dataframe as follows

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import timedelta


newdf = pd.concat(
    [
        pd.DataFrame(
            {
                'DataFrom':
                pd.date_range(row.DateFrom, row.DateTo, freq='W-MON'),
                'DateTo':
                pd.date_range(
                    row.DateFrom + timedelta(days=6),
                    row.DateTo + timedelta(days=6),
                    freq='W'),
                'Catalog':
                row.Catalog,
                'Score':
                row.Score
            },
            columns=['DataFrom', 'DateTo', 'Catalog', 'Score'])
        for i, row in df.iterrows()
    ],
    ignore_index=True)
```

This prints the following output

```
newdf

    DataFrom    DateTo    Catalog   Score
0   2017-05-01  2017-05-07  ABC     20
1   2017-05-08  2017-05-14  ABC     20
2   2017-05-15  2017-05-21  ABC     20
3   2017-05-22  2017-05-28  WXY     30
4   2017-05-29  2017-06-04  WXY     30
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `melt` to get `DateFrom` and `DateTo` aligned, then `groupby(Catalog)` and `resample` on `DateTo` with forward-fill.
Reconstruct `DateFrom` using a `TimeDelta`.

```
melted = pd.melt(df, id_vars=["Catalog", "Score"], var_name="x", value_name="DateTo")

df2 = (
    melted.set_index(pd.to_datetime(melted.DateTo))
     .drop(["x", "DateTo"],1)
     .groupby("Catalog", as_index=False)
     .resample("W")
     .ffill()
     .reset_index(level=1)
)

df2["DateFrom"] = df2.DateTo - pd.Timedelta("6 days")
```

Output:

```
df2[df.columns]
                   Catalog  Score
Catalog date                     
ABC     2017-05-07     ABC     20
        2017-05-14     ABC     20
        2017-05-21     ABC     20
WXY     2017-05-28     WXY     30
        2017-06-04     WXY     30
```

Data:

```
df
     DateFrom      DateTo Catalog  Score
0  2017-05-01  2017-05-21     ABC     20
1  2017-05-22  2017-06-04     WXY     30
```