# Convert Pandas dataframe row containing datetime range along to new dataframe with a row for each date along with hours included on that date

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So, I have StartDateTime and EndDateTime columns in my dataframe, and I want to produce a new dataframe with a row for each date in the datetime range, but I also want the number of hours of that date that are included in the date range.

```
In [11]: sessions = pd.DataFrame({'Start':['2018-01-01 13:00:00','2018-03-01 16:30:00'],
'End':['2018-01-03 07:00:00','2018-03-02 06:00:00'],'User':['Dan','Fred']})
In [12]: sessions
Out[12]:    
                Start                 End User
0 2018-01-01 13:00:00 2018-01-03 07:00:00  Dan 
1 2018-03-01 16:30:00 2018-03-02 06:00:00 Fred
```

Desired dataframe:

```
Date        Hours   User
2018-01-01  11      Dan
2018-01-02  24      Dan
2018-01-02  7       Dan
2018-03-01  7.5     Fred
2018-03-02  6       Fred
```

I've seen a lot of examples that just produced a dataframe for each date in the date range (e.g. [Expanding pandas data frame with date range in columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42151886/expanding-pandas-data-frame-with-date-range-in-columns))
but nothing with the additional field of hours per date included in the range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know it's the cleanest solution, but it seems to work.

```
In [13]: sessions = pd.DataFrame({'Start':['2018-01-01 13:00:00','2018-03-01 16:30:00'],
'End':['2018-01-03 07:00:00','2018-03-02 06:00:00'],'User':['Dan','Fred']})
```

convert Start and End to Datetime

```
In [14]: sessions['Start']=pd.to_datetime(sessions['Start'])
    sessions['End']=pd.to_datetime(sessions['End'])
```

create a row for each date in range

```
In [15]: dailyUsage = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame({'Date': 
pd.date_range(pd.to_datetime(row.Start).date(), row.End.date(), freq='D'),'Start':row.Start,
               'User': row.User,
               'End': row.End}, columns=['Date', 'Start','User', 'End']) 
           for i, row in sessions.iterrows()], ignore_index=True)
```

function to calcuate the hours on date, based on start datetime, end datetime, and specfic date

```
In [16]: def calcDuration(x):
    date=  x['Date']
    startDate = x['Start']
    endDate = x['End']

    #starts and stops on same day
    if endDate.date() == startDate.date():
        return (endDate - startDate).seconds/3600

    #this is on the start date
    if (date.to_pydatetime().date() - startDate.date()).days == 0:
        return 24 - startDate.hour

    #this is on the end date
    if (date.to_pydatetime().date() - endDate.date()).days == 0:
        return startDate.hour

    #this is on an interior date
    else:
        return 24
```

calculate hours for each date

```
In [17]: dailyUsage['hours'] = dailyUsage.apply(calcDuration,axis=1)

In [18]: dailyUsage.drop(['Start','End'],axis=1).head()
Out [18]: 
        Date User  hours
0 2018-01-01  Dan     11 
1 2018-01-02  Dan     24 
2 2018-01-03  Dan     13 
3 2018-03-01 Fred      8 
4 2018-03-02 Fred     16
```

Answer (score 0):

something like this would work as well, if you don't mind integers only;

```
df['date'] = df['Date'].dt.date
gb = df.groupby(['date', 'User'])['Date'].size()
print(gb)

date        User
2018-01-01  Dan     11
2018-01-02  Dan     24
2018-01-03  Dan      8
2018-03-01  Fred     8
2018-03-02  Fred     6
Name: Date, dtype: int64
```