# Pandas given start and end date, bin them into weekly frequency and count

Tags: python, pandas

I have start data and end data define a period. I want to aggregate such periods into weekly, and counts the number of days allocated in each week.

I think I have to use pd.cut with weekly bins. I am thinking to convert periods into column of dates first. Then use group by id and resample to do the count. I am stucked in convert periods to daily column.

I am struggle to get the desired results by following [Expanding pandas data frame with date range in columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42151886/expanding-pandas-data-frame-with-date-range-in-columns)

```
# dataframe
prod_id = ['a', 'a', 'b', 'c']
start_date = ['2019-01-15',  '2019-08-10', '2019-06-15',  '2019-07-10']
end_date = ['2019-01-28',  '2019-08-15', '2019-07-15',  '2019-07-22']
d = {'id': prod_id, 'start': start_date, 'end': end_date}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d)
df = df[['id', 'start', 'end']]
df['start'] = pd.to_datetime(df['start'])
df['end'] = pd.to_datetime(df['end'])

# bins
freq = 'W'
bins = pd.date_range(pd.to_datetime('2018-10-01'), pd.to_datetime('2019-10-20'), freq=freq).tolist()
```

the expected results is something like

[image]

Comment: how can the week end before it's even begun ? i don't understand how you merge the week end onto your df, can you explain the logic abit more?

Comment: didn't address it clean. The start and end columns in the results are just repeated of the inputs. the week_ends is the bins eg. the week of 01/13 - 01/20 will be in week ends of 01/20/2019, which should counts as 5 days 01/15 -01/20

Answer (score 1):

OK, I think I figure out one way to get around it. Not an elegant one, so still waiting for better solution. (particularly prefer not to resample to daily)

following  [Expanding pandas data frame with date range in columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42151886/expanding-pandas-data-frame-with-date-range-in-columns)

the trick is to introduce another column, so the repeated id can be distinguished separately for groupby. below is the codes

```
prod_id = ['a', 'a', 'b', 'c']
# add this to differetiate prod_id "a" 
num_id = [1, 2, 3, 4]
start_date = ['2019-01-15',  '2019-08-10', '2019-06-15',  '2019-07-10']
end_date = ['2019-01-28',  '2019-08-15', '2019-07-15',  '2019-07-22']
d = {'id': prod_id, 'nd': num_id, 'start': start_date, 'end': end_date}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d)
df = df[['id', 'nd', 'start', 'end']]
df['start'] = pd.to_datetime(df['start'])
df['end'] = pd.to_datetime(df['end'])    


df_melt = df.melt(id_vars=['id', 'nd'],value_name='date')
# first aggregate to daily
df_aggr_D = df_melt.groupby(['id', 'nd']).apply(lambda x: x.set_index('date').resample('D').pad()).drop(columns=['id','nd', 'variable']).reset_index()
df_aggr_D.drop(columns=['nd'], inplace=True)
# the aggregate to weekly
df_aggr_W = df_aggr_D.set_index('date').groupby('id').resample('W').count()
df_aggr_W.loc[df_aggr_W['id']!=0].rename(columns={'id':'count'})
```

[image]

Comment: Looks complex but I'm glad you were able to get there.