# Divide rows from yearly to monthly values pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, date, split, row

I am trying to divide line items with a start and end date into multiple rows based on months.
Values should be calculated based on number of days in the specific months.

For instance, data of 1 line item:

| id | StartDate | EndDate | Annual |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abc | 12/12/2018 | 01/12/2019 | 120,450 |

expected output:

| id | Month | Year | Monthly volume |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abc | 12 | 2018 | 6,600 |
| abc | 1 | 2019 | 10,230 |
| abc | 2 | 2019 | 9,240 |
| abc | 3 | 2019 | 10,230 |
| abc | 4 | 2019 | 9,900 |
| abc | 5 | 2019 | 10,230 |
| abc | 6 | 2019 | 9,900 |
| abc | 7 | 2019 | 10,230 |
| abc | 8 | 2019 | 10,230 |
| abc | 9 | 2019 | 9,900 |
| abc | 10 | 2019 | 10,230 |
| abc | 11 | 2019 | 9,900 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few things for next time you ask.

- This is a case where there are existing answers, so always try google
  first to reduce duplication. Other post is referenced in code below.
- You should also always include the code you already tried, SO doesn't
  like to do your homework, but we will help you with it.
- You should include a more readily reproduced dataframe. I shouldn't have to copy paste to build it, as in below code.
- you are clearly doing something to convert the Annual total to a monthly volume but you do not explain this, so do not expect it to be done for you.
- Lastly, this code doesn't convert to separate month and year columns, but once you have the date, this should be trivial for you to do (or to google how to do).

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    data = [['abc','12/12/2018','12/01/2019',120450]], 
    columns = ['id', 'startDate', 'EndDate', 'Annual'] 
)
df['startDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['startDate'])
df['EndDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['EndDate'])
# pd.bdate_range(start="2020/12/16", end="2020/12/26", freq="C", weekmask="Sat Sun")
# %%
df_start_end = df.melt(id_vars=['id', 'Annual'],value_name='date')
# credit to u/gen
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42151886/expanding-pandas-data-frame-with-date-range-in-columns
df = (
    df_start_end.groupby('id')
    .apply(lambda x: x.set_index('date')
    .resample('M').pad())
    .drop(columns=['id','variable'])
    .reset_index()
)
print(df)
```

Comment: Works perfect. Will take you're comments into account for future questions.