# Pandas - Number of Months Between Two Dates

Tags: python, pandas, date, diff

I think this should be simple but what I've seen are techniques that involve iterating over a dataframe date fields to determine the diff between two dates. And I'm having trouble with it. I'm familiar with MSSQL DATEDIFF so I thought Pandas datetime would have something similar. I perhaps it does but I'm missing it.

Is there a Pandonic way of determing the number of months as an integer between two dates (datetime) without the need to iterate? Keep in mind that there potentially are millions of rows so performance is a consideration.

The dates are datetime objects and the result would like this - new column being Month:

```
Date1           Date2         Months
2016-04-07      2017-02-01    11
2017-02-01      2017-03-05    1
```

Answer (score 103, accepted):

Here is a very simple answer my friend:

```
df['nb_months'] = ((df.date2 - df.date1)/np.timedelta64(1, 'M'))
```

and now:

```
df['nb_months'] = df['nb_months'].astype(int)
```

Comment: I get a float when running this. It that what you expected?

Comment: just convert to integer with astype('int') bro

Comment: df['month'] = ((df.date2 - df.date1) / np.timedelta64(1, 'M')).astype(int) does the trick. Completes quickly. Thanks bro.

Comment: not better bro, just different. the advantage of my solution is that the output is a float, not an object.

Comment: I concur with discort. The other solution is better as it takes care of rounding. The .asType method suggested here fails with NaT rows (which you may get if you had just calculated a 'Next Date' field where the last row is always a NaT)

Comment: Beware: this rounds to, e.g., 0 months between Feb 1 and March 1 -- is that what you really want?  It gives slightly more or less than a whole number of months depending on the months in question.  For instance, `(pd.Timestamp('2018-03-01') - pd.Timestamp('2018-02-01')) / np.timedelta64(1, 'M') == 0.91993675`.  @piRSquared's solution, or `.round()` is probably better.

Comment: If you read the comments you would notice I suggest to use `astype(int)` which completely solves this point. Adding this more explicitly.

Comment: Just note that this returns 9 months for the first row, instead of OP's desired 11. I'd say that's correct - the interval is almost but not quite 10 months, and rounding down is usually what you want for timedeltas - but thought the discrepancy worth pointing out.

Comment: You will face an issue with rounding with this method.
Use df['nb_months'] = df['nb_months'].round(0).astype(int)

Comment: I prefer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49700898/pandas-date-range-subtracting-numpy-timedelta-gives-odd-result-time-becomes-n

Comment: Assuming you are running Python 3,  you could use the // operator to do integer division to get the integer `df['nb_months'] = (df.date2 - df.date1) // np.timedelta64(1, 'M')`

Answer (score 49):

An alternative, possibly more elegant solution is
`delta = df.Date2.dt.to_period('M') - df.Date1.dt.to_period('M')`, which avoids rounding errors.

Since Pandas 0.24, this expression return an offset, which can be turned into an integer with `delta.apply(lambda x: x.n)`

Comment: I think this is the more correct answer, as rounding errors sure cause trouble.

Comment: to return Series of int, use following code;
`from operator import attrgetter`
`(df.Date2.dt.to_period('M') - df.Date1.dt.to_period('M')).to_period('M')).apply(attrgetter('n'))`
as per [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54465409)

Comment: Doesn't work for pandas version > 0.24.0. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40923820/pandas-timedelta-in-months) answer for updated code.

Answer (score 30):

```
df.assign(
    Months=
    (df.Date2.dt.year - df.Date1.dt.year) * 12 +
    (df.Date2.dt.month - df.Date1.dt.month)
)

       Date1      Date2  Months
0 2016-04-07 2017-02-01      10
1 2017-02-01 2017-03-05       1
```

Comment: This one works as well. I get 10 and 1 months. With @Noobie solution I get 9 and 1. So this one is inclusive. Depending on my needs for any particular project both are super useful. Thanks.

Comment: or simply:
df["Months"] = (df.Date2.dt.year - df.Date1.dt.year) * 12 +
    (df.Date2.dt.month - df.Date1.dt.month)

Answer (score 13):

This works with pandas 1.1.1:

```
df['Months'] = df['Date2'].dt.to_period('M').astype(int) - df['Date1'].dt.to_period('M').astype(int)

df

# Out[11]: 
#        Date1      Date2  Months
# 0 2016-04-07 2017-02-01      10
# 1 2017-02-01 2017-03-05       1
```

Comment: Thank you, some of the other solutions don't work anymore

Comment: For future reference, I got an error when using `astype(int)` since it's no longer supported. Use `astype('int64')` instead.

Answer (score 7):

Just a small addition to @pberkes answer.
In case you want the answer as integer values and **NOT as pandas._libs.tslibs.offsets.MonthEnd**, just append `.n` to the above code.

```
(pd.to_datetime('today').to_period('M') - pd.to_datetime('2020-01-01').to_period('M')).n
# [Out]:
# 7
```

Answer (score 4):

There are two notions of difference in time, which are both correct in a certain sense. Let us compare the difference in months between July 31 and September 01:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

dtr = pd.date_range(start="2016-07-31", end="2016-09-01", freq="D")
delta1 = int((dtr[-1] - dtr[0])/np.timedelta64(1,'M'))
delta2 = (dtr[-1].to_period('M') - dtr[0].to_period('M')).n
print(delta1,delta2)
```

Using numpy's timedelta, `delta1=1`, which is correct given that there is only one month in between, but `delta2=2`, which is also correct given that September is still two months away in July. In most cases, both will give the same answer, but one might be more correct than the other given the context.