# Pandas date_range - subtracting numpy timedelta gives odd result, time becomes not 0:00:00

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, datetime, timedelta

I am trying to generate a set of dates with pandas date_range functionality. Then I want to iterate over this range and subtract several months from each of the dates (exact number of month is determined in loop) to get a new date.

I get some very odd results when I do this.

MVP:

```
#get date range
dates = pd.date_range(start = '1/1/2013', end='1/1/2018', freq=str(test_size)+'MS', closed='left', normalize=True)
#take first date as example
date = dates[0]
date
Timestamp('2013-01-01 00:00:00', freq='3MS')
```

So far so good.

Now let's say I want to go just one month back from this date. I define numpy timedelta (it supports months for definition, while pandas' timedelta doesn't):

```
#get timedelta of 1 month
deltaGap = np.timedelta64(1,'M')
#subtract one month from date
date - deltaGap
Timestamp('2012-12-01 13:30:54', freq='3MS')
```

Why so? Why I get 13:30:54 in time component instead of midnight.

Moreover, if I subtract more than 1 month it the shift becomes so large that I lose a whole day:

```
#let's say I want to subtract both 2 years and then 1 month
deltaTrain = np.timedelta64(2,'Y')
#subtract 2 years and then subtract 1 month 
date - deltaTrain - deltaGap
Timestamp('2010-12-02 01:52:30', freq='3MS')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've had similar issues with `timedelta`, and the solution I've ended up using was using `relativedelta` from `dateutil`, which is specifically built for this kind of application (taking into account all the calendar weirdness like leap years, weekdays, etc...). For example given:

```
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

date = dates[0]

>>> date
Timestamp('2013-01-01 00:00:00', freq='10MS')

deltaGap = relativedelta(months=1)

>>> date-deltaGap
Timestamp('2012-12-01 00:00:00', freq='10MS')

deltaGap = relativedelta(years=2, months=1)

>>> date-deltaGap
Timestamp('2010-12-01 00:00:00', freq='10MS')
```

Check out the [documentation](http://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/relativedelta.html) for more info on `relativedelta`

**The issues with `numpy.timedelta64`**

I think that the problem with `np.timedelta` is revealed in these 2 parts of the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.datetime.html):

> There are two Timedelta units (‘Y’, years and ‘M’, months) which are treated specially, because how much time they represent changes depending on when they are used. While a timedelta day unit is equivalent to 24 hours, there is no way to convert a month unit into days, because different months have different numbers of days.

and

> The length of the span is the range of a 64-bit integer times the length of the date or unit. For example, the time span for ‘W’ (week) is exactly 7 times longer than the time span for ‘D’ (day), and the time span for ‘D’ (day) is exactly 24 times longer than the time span for ‘h’ (hour).

So the timedeltas are fine for hours, weeks, months, days, because these are non-variable timespans. However, months and years are variable in length (think leap years), and so to take this into account, `numpy` takes some sort of "average" (I guess). One `numpy` "year" seems to be one year, 5 hours, 49 minutes and 12 seconds, while one `numpy` "month" seems to be 30 days, 10 hours, 29 minutes and 6 seconds.

```
# Adding one numpy month adds 30 days + 10:29:06:
deltaGap = np.timedelta64(1,'M')
date+deltaGap
# Timestamp('2013-01-31 10:29:06', freq='10MS')

# Adding one numpy year adds 1 year + 05:49:12:
deltaGap = np.timedelta64(1,'Y')
date+deltaGap
# Timestamp('2014-01-01 05:49:12', freq='10MS')
```

This is not so easy to work with, which is why I would just go to `relativedelta`, which is much more intuitive (to me).

Comment: Thank you! Makes perfect sense. Somehow missed relativedelta while searching for approaches

Comment: No problem! Yeah it's kind of weird. I like this part of the `numpy` docs: *"there is no way to convert a month unit into days, because different months have different numbers of days"*, `relativedelta` apparently does the impossible!

Answer (score 1):

You can try using [`pd.DateOffset`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#dateoffset-objects) which is mainly used for applying offset logic (month, year, hour) on dates format.

```
# get random dates
dates = pd.date_range(start = '1/1/2013', freq='H',periods=100,closed='left', normalize=True)

#take first date as example
date = dates[0]

# subtract a month
dates[0] - pd.DateOffset(months=1)
Timestamp('2012-12-01 00:00:00')

# to apply this on all dates
new_dates = list(map(lambda x: x - pd.DateOffset(months=1), dates))
```