# How to calculate variance in months between dates using relativedelta

Tags: python, dataframe, datetime, relativedelta

I am trying to add a new column to my DataFrame and want it to return the difference in months between two dates which are in two other columns.

I've tried several ways so far, including:

- simply subtracting the dates and then dividing by 360
  `df['TimeInJob'] = (df['OrderDate'] - df['HireDate'] / 360)`
- the `to_timedelta` method and different parameter settings
- I attempted this but wasn't sure about the variables they used:

`for i in df.index:`
    `df.at[i, 'diff'] = relativedelta.relativedelta(df.ix[i, 'start'], df.ix[i, 'end'])`

This is my latest attempt:

`from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta`

`df['MonthsInJob'] = relativedelta(qf['OrderDate'], df['HireDate'])`

but get error message: "ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()." I have no idea where to include truth values

I need the new column to have the difference in months

Answer (score 1):

I found this (https://stackoverflow.com/a/42822819/10925117) and it worked for the ultimate end I needed:
`df['nb_months'] = ((df.date2 - df.date1)/np.timedelta64(1, 'M'))`

but still curious about how to get the relativedelta method to work here.