# Add consecutive month number to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a df with information about sales per month-year like this:

```
sales     month-year
2         2017-01
5         2017-01
4         2017-02
3         2017-03
3         2017-03
```

I want to add a consecutive month number like this:

```
 sales     month-year   month-number
    2         2017-01   1
    5         2017-01   1
    4         2017-02   2
    3         2017-03   3
    3         2017-03   3
```

The original df contains data for multiple years, so 2018-01 should be 13 etc..

What is the best way to do this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Try this!
[Pandas - Number of Months Between Two Dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42822768/pandas-number-of-months-between-two-dates/42822819)

```
df['month-number'] = ((df["month-year"] - df["month-year"][0])/np.timedelta64(1, 'M')).astype(int)
```