# Number of months between two dates while one date is given

Tags: pandas

### Input df

```
Date1            
2019-01-23      
2020-02-01
```

note: The type of `Date1` is `datetime64[ns]`.

### Goal

I want to calculate month diff between Date1 column and `'2019-01-01'`.

### Try and Ref

I try the answers from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42822768/pandas-number-of-months-between-two-dates) , but it failed as below:

```
df['Date1'].dt.to_period('M') - pd.to_datetime('2019-01-01').to_period('M')
```

- note:pandas version: 1.1.5

Comment: Did you convert the `Date1` to an actual date type with `pd.to_datetime()`?

Comment: @PauloMarques not necessary, see my update.

Comment: @Jack - So you want to ignore the Year and only calculate the month difference?  For.e.g month difference between 2020-02-01  & 2019-01-01 is '1'?

Comment: @sharathnatraj no, it must conclude year. For your example, it will be 13.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution should be changed by convert periods to integers and for second value is used one element list `['2019-01-01']`:

```
df['new'] = (df['Date1'].dt.to_period('M').astype(int) - 
             pd.to_datetime(['2019-01-01']).to_period('M').astype(int))
print (df)
       Date1  new
0 2019-01-23    0
1 2020-02-01   13
```

If compare solutions:

```
rng = pd.date_range('1900-04-03', periods=3000, freq='MS')
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date1': rng})  


In [106]: %%timeit
     ...: date_ref = pd.to_datetime('2019-01-01')
     ...: df["mo_since_2019_01"] = (df.Date1.dt.year - date_ref.year).values*12 + (df.Date1.dt.month - date_ref.month)
     ...: 
1.57 ms ± 8.18 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [107]: %%timeit
     ...: df['new'] = (df['Date1'].dt.to_period('M').astype(int) - pd.to_datetime(['2019-01-01']).to_period('M').astype(int))
     ...: 
1.32 ms ± 19.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Apply are loops under the hood, so slowier:

```
In [109]: %%timeit
     ...: start = pd.to_datetime("2019-01-01")
     ...: df['relative_months'] = df['Date1'].apply(lambda end: relative_months(start, end, freq="M"))
     ...: 
25.7 s ± 729 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [110]: %%timeit
     ...: rd = df['Date1'].apply(lambda x:relativedelta(x,date(2019,1,1)))
     ...: mon = rd.apply(lambda x: ((x.years * 12) + x.months))
     ...: df['Diff'] = mon
     ...: 
94.2 ms ± 431 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work:

```
date_ref = pd.to_datetime('2019-01-01')
df["mo_since_2019_01"] = (df.Date1.dt.year - date_ref.year).values*12 + (df.Date1.dt.month - date_ref.month)

month_delta = (date2.year - date1.year)*12 + (date2.month - date1.month)
```

output:

```
       Date1  mo_since_2019_01
0 2019-01-23                 0
1 2020-02-01                13
```

Comment: I don't understand your answer , it seems not matching my question.

Answer (score 1):

With this solution, you won't need further imports as it simply calculates the length of the `pd.date_range()` between your fixed start date and varying end date:

```
def relative_months(start, end, freq="M"):
    if start < end:
        x = len(pd.date_range(start=start,end=end,freq=freq))
    else:
        x = - len(pd.date_range(start=end,end=start,freq=freq))
    return x

start = pd.to_datetime("2019-01-01")
df['relative_months'] = df['Date1'].apply(lambda end: relative_months(start, end, freq="M"))
```

In your specific case, I think [anon01's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65298389/565489) should be the quickest/ favorable; my variant however allows the use of [generic frequency strings](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#dateoffset-objects) for date offsets like `'M'`, `'D'`, … and allows you to specifically handle the edge case of "negative" relative offsets (i.e. what happens if your comparison date is not earlier than all dates in `Date1`).

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
rd = df['Date1'].apply(lambda x:relativedelta(x,date(2019,1,1)))
mon = rd.apply(lambda x: ((x.years * 12) + x.months))
df['Diff'] = mon
```

Input:

```
        Date1
0  2019-01-23
1  2020-02-01
2  2020-05-01
3  2020-06-01
```

Output:

```
       Date1  Diff
0 2019-01-23     0
1 2020-02-01    13
2 2020-05-01    16
3 2020-06-01    17
```

Comment: Please remember to include the necessary imports, I'm _guessing_: `from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta` and `from datetime import date`