# Subtract datetime to have delta in months

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a dataframe with multiple dates, such as **'2019-05-01'** and I want to substract it to get e.g. **4** (2019-09-01 - 2019-05-01). Those are two columns.

Comment: Are those 'strings' or datetime datatypes?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/42822768/10197418

Comment: Do you use Pandas dataframe or PySpark dataframe?

Comment: Those are datetime datatypes

Comment: I use Pandas dadaframe

Answer (score 0):

```
df['delta'] = [ (x.year -  y.year) * 12 + (x.month -  y.month) for x, y in zip(df['date1'],df['date2'])]
```

Comment: You neither need a list comprehension nor zip, see the dupes I linked.

Comment: I'm afraid that this solution doesn't work - it shows wrong numbers eg. differences between Jan and FEB shows 0 whereas my solution shows 1