# How to find number of months between two dates where datatype is datetime64[ns]

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have two fields in a dataframe, both of which are `datetime64[ns]`

I thought I could just do this...

```
df_hist['MonthsBetween'] = (df_hist.Last_Date - df_hist.Begin_Time) / pd.Timedelta(months=1)
```

One field has only a data and one has a date/time, but both are of datatype datetime64[ns]. I Googled this and it seems like it should work, but I'm getting an error message saying:

```
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

I thought these were both datetime64[ns], and neither str or int.

Comment: can you provide a reproducible input as example?

Comment: The subtraction between two datetime columns should work fine; Maybe pd.Timedelta with `months` is a problem? Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42822768/pandas-number-of-months-between-two-dates

Comment: How many months between Jan 31 and Feb 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You can use to_period to take months and then subtract

```
    df_hist['MonthsBetween'] = df_hist['Last_Date'].dt.to_period('M').astype(int) - df_hist['Begin_Time'].dt.to_period('M').astype(int)
df
Out[123]: 
                 Last_Date      Begin_Time  Months
0  2022-01-01 00:00:00 2022-03-01       2
1  2022-01-01 12:00:00 2022-03-02       2
2  2022-01-02 00:00:00 2022-03-03       2
3  2022-01-02 12:00:00 2022-03-04       2
4  2022-01-03 00:00:00 2022-03-05       2
5  2022-01-03 12:00:00 2022-03-06       2
6  2022-01-04 00:00:00 2022-03-07       2
7  2022-01-04 12:00:00 2022-03-08       2
```

### dtypes of  date columns should be datetime64[ns]

```
df_hist.dtypes
Out[125]: 
Last_Date     datetime64[ns]
Begin_Time     datetime64[ns]
Months             int64
dtype: object
```

Comment: I should have mentioned it before. I tried that, or something very similar, and I got this error.  AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'dt'

Comment: what does df_hist.dtypes gives you ?

Comment: Now...I'm getting....ValueError: cannot assemble with duplicate keys
I've never seen this before...

Comment: Ultimately, this worked for me.

df_hist['MonthsBetween'] = ((df_hist.Last_Date - df_hist.Begin_Time)/np.timedelta64(1, 'M'))

The data types are object now!