# How to convert datetime to timestamp and calculate difference between dates using lambda function

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7, python-datetime

I need to convert a variable i created into a timestamp from a datetime.

I need it in a timestamp format to perform a lambda function against my pandas series, which is stored as a datetime64. 
The lambda function should find the difference in months between startDate and the entire pandas series. Please help?

I've tried using relativedelta to calculate the difference in months but I'm not sure how to implement it with a pandas series.

```
from datetime import datetime 
import pandas as pd
from dateutil.relativedelta  import relativedelta as rd

#open the data set and store in the series ('df')
file = pd.read_csv("test_data.csv")
df = pd.DataFrame(file)

#extract column "AccountOpenedDate into a data frame"
open_date_data = pd.Series.to_datetime(df['AccountOpenedDate'], format = '%Y/%m/%d')

#set the variable startDate
dateformat = '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S'
set_date  = datetime.strptime('2017/07/01 00:00:00',dateformat)
startDate = datetime.timestamp(set_date)

#This function calculates the difference in months between two dates: ignore 

def month_delta(start_date, end_date):
    delta = rd(end_date, start_date)
    # >>> relativedelta(years=+2, months=+3, days=+28)
    return 12 * delta.years + delta.months

d1 = datetime(2017, 7, 1)
d2 = datetime(2019, 10, 29)
total_months = month_delta(d1, d2)

# Apply a lambda function to each row by adding 5 to each value in each column
dfobj = open_date_data.apply(lambda x: x + startDate)
print(dfobj)
```

I'm only using a single column from the loaded data set. It's a date column in the following format ("%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S"). I want to find the difference in months between startDate and all the dates in the series.

Comment: I used the following function to calculate the difference in months between two dates. However, I'm not sure how to use this with startDate and my pandas series

Comment: ```This function calculates the difference in months between two dates: ignore 

def month_delta(start_date, end_date):
    delta = rd(end_date, start_date)
    # >>> relativedelta(years=+2, months=+3, days=+28)
    return 12 * delta.years + delta.months

d1 = datetime(2017, 7, 1)
d2 = datetime(2019, 10, 29)
total_months = month_delta(d1, d2)```

Comment: @glibdud. I've added the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I don't have your original csv, I've made up some sample data and hopefully managed to shorten your code quite a bit:

```
open_date_data = pd.Series(pd.date_range('2017/07/01', periods=10, freq='M')) 
startDate = pd.Timestamp("2017/07/01")
```

Then, with help from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40924041/3763302) to get the appropriate `month_diff` formula:

```
def month_diff(a, b):
    return 12 * (a.year - b.year) + (a.month - b.month)

open_date_data.apply(lambda x: month_diff(x, startDate))
```

Comment: thank you for this. I've made some changes to my script. I'm getting the following error  ```line 48, in month_diff
    return 12 * (a.year - b.year) + (a.month - b.month)

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'year'``` I'll share the changes I made to the script.

Comment: @MgMogaki Please don't move the goalposts by changing the problem after someone has already answered. If you have a different issue after solving this one (or going a different direction), that should be a new question.

Comment: @MgMogaki Your problem was that you did not create the `startDate` variable in the same way that I did. I now see that you have taken my answer and posted it as your own, which is highly frowned upon.

Comment: @ glibdud apologies

Comment: @Tom thank you very much for the assistance. I thought it would be a straight implementation into my existing code. Sincerest Apologies.

Comment: @MgMogaki The appropriate thing to do would be to delete your answer, as I have taken the time to provide you with a solution.