# How to resample a Time Series on given irregular dates

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
date_index = pd.date_range("2010-01-31", "2010-12-31", freq="M")
df  = pd.Series(range(12), index=date_index)

dates = date_index[1::2]
```

The Series `df` is of monthly frequency, and we want to resample by adding up the value between the dates as given by the `dates` variable.

`df` is:

```
2010-01-31     0
2010-02-28     1
2010-03-31     2
2010-04-30     3
2010-05-31     4
2010-06-30     5
2010-07-31     6
2010-08-31     7
2010-09-30     8
2010-10-31     9
2010-11-30    10
2010-12-31    11
Freq: M, dtype: int64
```

`dates` is

```
DatetimeIndex(['2010-02-28', '2010-04-30', '2010-06-30', '2010-08-31',
               '2010-10-31', '2010-12-31'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='2M')
```

The expected result should be:

```
2010-02-28     1
2010-04-30     5
2010-06-30     9
2010-08-31     13
2010-10-31     17
2010-12-31    21
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idea is replace not matched values of `date`s to missing values by [`Series.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) with `bfill` for bacj filling missing values and then aggregate `sum`:

```
date_index = pd.date_range("2010-01-31", "2010-12-31", freq="M")
s  = pd.Series(range(12), index=date_index)

dates = date_index[1::2]

a = s.index.to_series().where(s.index.isin(dates)).bfill()
out = s.groupby(a).sum()
print(out)
2010-02-28     1
2010-04-30     5
2010-06-30     9
2010-08-31    13
2010-10-31    17
2010-12-31    21
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 2):

Not a general resampling solution but for your concrete question of adding up the values between the dates you could use

```
res = df.cumsum()[dates].diff()
res[0] = df[dates[0]]
res = res.astype(df.dtype)
```

Result:

```
2010-02-28     1
2010-04-30     5
2010-06-30     9
2010-08-31    13
2010-10-31    17
2010-12-31    21
```

Answer (score 1):

For your specific example, where `df[0] = 0`, it is a simple [`resample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.21.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) with `sum()` aggregation, skipping `df[0]`.

```
df_resampled = df[1::].resample('2M').sum()

print(df_resampled)
2010-02-28     1
2010-04-30     5
2010-06-30     9
2010-08-31    13
2010-10-31    17
2010-12-31    21
Freq: 2M, dtype: int64
```

In case `df[0] != 0`, you can still make an easy workaround by adding `df[0]` to the first element of `df_resampled`:

```
df_resampled[0] = df_resampled[0] + df[0]
```

In case you want general resampling with period of two month, you can try to use the `loffset` parameter of `resample` and provide a function returning `pd.Timedelta` objects such, that it "floors" to the last day of each individual month. (See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40923820/pandas-timedelta-in-months) for how to get montly periods for `pd.Timedelta`)