# How to detect if pandas dataframe has duplicates between a two column range?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

I have a dataframe as follows:

| A | B | Monthfrom | Monthto |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| XCP25 | MW | 202006 | 202011 |
| XCP25 | MW | 202007 | 202012 |
| XCP25 | XY | 202006 | 202011 |
| FHA23 | CY | 202006 | 202011 |
| FHA23 | ZW | 202006 | 202011 |

If column A and B have the same row values, I need to detect if their Monthfrom and Monthto values match similar ranges. In the example, the first two rows match ranges between Monthfrom and Monthto values and have the same keys for column A and B. Any ideas how to detect this?

Answer (score 0):

First compute the range in months for each row (also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40923820/pandas-timedelta-in-months) for various options).

Then group by A, B and range and count the rows. Each row with a count greater 1 is one of the duplicates you are looking for.

```
df['Monthfrom'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Monthfrom, format='%Y%m').dt.to_period('M')
df['Monthto'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Monthto, format='%Y%m').dt.to_period('M')

df['range'] = df.Monthto.view('int') - df.Monthfrom.view('int')

counts = df.groupby(['A', 'B', 'range']).count()

duplicates = counts.loc[counts.Monthto > 1]
```