# Index a dataframe based on a date column

Tags: python, datetime, indexing, typeerror, train-test-split

I'd like to do a manual train-test-split for a random forest or linear regression on a dataframe called `whatever_df` based on the `Date` column. I would use this column to select all rows that have dates earlier than 3 months before the most recent one in the column to make a new dataframe called `train_df` with those older dates, and a `test_df` with all the dates within the latest 3 months. In raw format the dataframe looks like:

```py
        PC1         PC2         Date
0      -0.319258    -0.042817   2019-05-24
1      -0.246079    0.131233    2019-05-24
2      -0.037325    0.562841    2019-05-24
3      -0.080725    0.594007    2019-05-24
4       0.133341    0.322822    2019-05-24
             ...    ...   ...   ...
3607    -3.583419   3.766158    2022-06-26
3608    -3.305263   4.019327    2022-06-26
3609    -2.913036   4.854316    2022-06-26
3610    -2.755733   4.873996    2022-06-26
3611    -2.535929   4.582312    2022-06-26
```

So what I'd want for `train_df` would be all the rows where `Date` is up through March 2022 inclusive and `test_df` would be all the rows for March 2022-June 2022. I know I could just hardcode this but I would like a dynamic way to select rows based on month values, and I know with `datetime` formatted columns I could find the newest date with just `max(df['Date'])` but I'm not sure how to say in Python `subtract 3 months from that`

I have tried this:

```py
whatever_df['Month'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(whatever_df['Date']).month
```

To get

```
     PC1        PC2         Date      Month
0   -0.319258   -0.042817   2019-05-24  5
1   -0.246079   0.131233    2019-05-24  5
2   -0.037325   0.562841    2019-05-24  5
3   -0.080725   0.594007    2019-05-24  5
4   0.133341    0.322822    2019-05-24  5
... ... ... ... ...
3607    -3.583419   3.766158    2022-06-26  6
3608    -3.305263   4.019327    2022-06-26  6
3609    -2.913036   4.854316    2022-06-26  6
3610    -2.755733   4.873996    2022-06-26  6
3611    -2.535929   4.582312    2022-06-26  6
```

And I know I could use:

```
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
```

To subtract 3 months from the `Month` column, however I'm not sure how that would work with January and February. Any ideas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas Timedelta in months](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40923820/pandas-timedelta-in-months)

Comment: Hi there, not exactly. I posted an elegant pythonic solution below that solves my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution

```py
train_df = whatever_df[whatever_df['Date'] <= max(whatever_df['Date']) - relativedelta(months = 3)]

test_df = whatever_df[whatever_df['Date'] > max(whatever_df['Date']) - relativedelta(months = 3)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to use `dateutil`'s features, a PyData type can be used directly

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import numpy as np
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"date": pd.Series("2022-08-30", dtype="datetime[ns]")})
>>> df["date"]
0   2022-08-30
Name: date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
>>> df["date"] + np.timedelta64(2, 'M')
0   2022-10-29 20:58:12
Name: date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: Interesting, thank you. I figured out a quick and easy solution that I'll post below.